# How to convert a JSON array to a String

Tags: iphone, json

I have a login page and it is connected to webservice for authentication. If the username and password is wrong we get the result string `{"status":"400"}`. I want to convert or format this json to a string like `login-failed` or something. How can I do this?

Comment: Well, you'd put together a table of some sort relating status value to message.

Comment: @HotLicks sorrry i didnt get u.thanks

Comment: ...so badly hoping this is not a `gimme teh codez` question.

Comment: @Till -- I suspect that's what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a JSON response from the web service.. Use a JSON parser like SBJSON or JSONKit to get the data from the webservice (this can be done using the NSURLConnection ) and then convert that the data to NSString, Feed this string to the JSON parser and get the dictionary. Use the output you get in this dictionary to display appropriate message to the user... you can use this tutorial.. http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using json to send information to the browser via ajax.
this might help start the things:

```
$.getJSON('yourJsonPhpFile.php', function(data) {
 if(data.status == 400)
  alert('login failed');
 else{
  //success
 }
});
```

this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSRange success;

    success =[[responseString lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[@"200" lowercaseString]];

    if(success.location != NSNotFound )
    {

        //u got "success" in some where in responseString

        //login success

    }
    else{

        //u didn't get "success" in any where in responseString

        //login failed

    }

}
```

Comment: but i only get 400 for unsucess and 200 for sucess login